# How to apply .diff patch with Eclipse to HtmlUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, diff, htmlunit

I'm trying to patch HtmlUnit with the patches at the bottom of [this](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2962074&group_id=47038&atid=448269) page. I can see how to apply patches from Eclipse, but I can't figure out how to apply these particular patches. I had the JARs initially, but then I realised I'd need to source, so I obtained those, but still no luck.

In the patch I see:

```
--- a/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.java
```

and etc. but what is up with the 'a/htmlunit'? I have the packages and "src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.java" (for example) is easily locatable, but not a/htmlunit. I can't really figure out how to apply this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, patches come with prefixes, kind of like putting the previous version in directory `a`, and the new version in directory `b` and just diffing them to produce the patch, only with version control systems, you don't really need to do that anymore. Most still do I suppose (at least git does by default).

Anyway, patch-tools have an option to skip a number of directory levels as prefix, in your case you'd have to skip two (a and htmlunit). Unfortunately, I don't know how this is done in eclipse, with vanilla unix patch you would need to add a `-p2` parameter. Poke around the UI, it ought to be there somewhere.